# How to handle back button when browser is not firing popstate event immediately

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

This question may sound weird, because most of the time popstate is fired synchronously as users press the back button.

However, W3C spec states that a UA (browser) is allowed to queue popstate when [traversing history](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#traverse-the-history) (see item 14), ie. `popstate` is fired asynchronously (even though URL has changed at this point).

Browser vendors interpret and implement this spec differently. [Mozilla decides](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/03/history-api-changes-in-firefox-4/) Firefox should be able to fire `popstate` before `load`, and for good reasons, so that slow images will not block `popstate`.

Chrome/Safari decides otherwise, and it leads our problem:

When managing history for a web app, it's often desirable to kick off history management as soon as possible, eg. at `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load`. **But in return, users are not able to back out of any `pushState`, because all `popstate` are queued until `load`.**

We are seeking advices for ways to handle such scenario. I come up with a few myself:

- Lazyload images, so `load` can fire ASAP.
- Block UI until `load` is fired.
- Init framework on `load` instead of `DOMContentLoaded`.

Are there better solutions?

**Update**: Things get ugly when there are ajax that fire before `load`, if those request result in DOM change, and DOM change happens to have some images, `load` is delayed until those images are loaded/timeout, meaning `popstate` is queued for even longer.

**Update 2**: To add a simple demo for it, visit this [jsbin page](http://jsbin.com/huxokosu/5/edit?html,js,console,output) with chrome and see `popstate` will be blocked until `load` is fired. You can compare result between cached image and uncached image.

Comment: When using the back button `popstate` should always fire immediately. The only case where it does not fire is when you refresh, but in that case you best base yourself on the URI either way (that's the point of a refresh). I must be missing something, but not sure what.

Comment: @DavidMulder I have added a jsbin page to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Ah, at least I get now that you're firing a history state change before the `load` has happened... why in the world are you doing that? Only a user should ever change state and the first time the app loads the back button shouldn't have any previous app specific states, so I am thoroughly confused what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DavidMulder We try very hard not to. But because 3G network is unstable, we see a lot of users got into issue where images are still loading (thus onload hasn't fired), but js framework has kicked in (as dom is ready). Because we handle history with js, when user cliked a link, pushstate is fired, but onload hasn't fired at this point, so when user click back button, we can't hanle it by listening to popstate.

Comment: Aaaah, yes, it all makes so much more sense now that I think about it in the context of slow mobile internet. Looking at my own apps I don't have enough graphics to ever encounter this problem, but at least I comprehend the issue now. Will think it over during the weekend and get back to you if I get any good ideas.

Comment: Lazy load will not only solve your problem as it can be used to serve smaller images for mobile viewers.

Comment: Are you building a single state application? If so I think its reasonable to block UI once while initialising. Each page sends a setup script, which initialises then resolves the original url request. People experience a slightly longer load time while your app inits, but should be speed up for future requests.

Comment: @bitinn Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try calling popstate during unload of the previous page. For eg, if you're in page 1 and want to move to page 2, instead of calling pop state during the load/ready of page 2, why don't you call pop state in the unload event of the page 1?

Not sure whether it satisfies your scenario. But I wasn't able to try it in your bin.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to invoke `popstate` directly, the only ways are with `history.back()` or `history.go(-n)`. They will be queued as mentioned.